# how to prerender/preprocess the data before displaying in custom admin module grid?

Tags: admin, grid

i have a custom admin module will print some data

```
$this->addColumn('product_old_values', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('adminlog')->__('product_old_values'),
    'align'     =>'left',
    'width'     => '20%',
    'index'     => 'product_old_values',
));
```

since product_old_values is a serialized array (a long string), how can i run unserialize(product_old_values) before displaying into a grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

render the column by below code

```
$this->addColumn('product_old_values', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('adminlog')->__('product_old_values'),
    'align'     =>'left',
    'renderer'  => 'Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Gridrender',
    'width'     => '20%',
    'index'     => 'product_old_values',
));
```

FOR RENDERING

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Gridrender extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
    {

        public function render(Varien_Object $row)
        {
         }
    }
```

for doing in grid class

```
 $this->addColumn('product_old_values', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('adminlog')->__('product_old_values'),
        'align'     =>'left',            
        'width'     => '20%',
        'index'     => 'product_old_values',
       'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image')

    ));



public function callback_image($value)
 {
   //write your code
 }
```

Comment: is it a must to open another class? can i do it in grid class?

Comment: you can do it with  'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image')

public function callback_image($value)
{
    $width = 20;
    $height = 20;
    return "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$value."' width=".$width." height=".$height."/>";
}
i used it for image

Comment: i update the answer..

Comment: @QaisarSatti 
can we return  custom HTML in callback_image() method ?

Comment: @dhavalsolanki yes

Comment: @QaisarSatti In magento 2.2.5 when I return html from callback_image() it returns one error that return value should be object of "widget" class

Comment: Here is exact error it throws "Frame callback host must be instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Widget"